# read dir error (readdir(): supplied argument is not a valid Directory resource )

Tags: php, readdir

tryin to read dir content with readdir($myDirectory), but i getting error:

```
readdir(): supplied argument is not a valid Directory resource
```

i checked with is_dir($myDirectory) is it directory or not, and yes, it is directory.

so, why i can not read dir? is it permissions problem?

just to mention, it's all on win xp box, not linux.

tnx in adv for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_dir()` needs a path. `readdir()` needs a resource. The resource needed by `readdir()` is retrieved thanks to the `opendir()` method.

> **dir_handle** (the parameter)
>
> The directory handle [resource](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) previously opened with [`opendir()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php). If the directory handle is not specified, the last link opened by [`opendir()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) is assumed.

For example :

> ```
> <?php
> if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
>     while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
>         if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
>             echo "$file\n";
>         }
>     }
>     closedir($handle);
> }
> ?>
> ```

---

**Resources :**

- [php.net - readdir()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)
- [php.net - is_dir()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)
- [php.net - opendir()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php)

Answer (score 1):

[`readdir`](http://php.net/readdir) expects a resource that was returned by [`opendir`](http://php.net/opendir), for example:

```
$handle = opendir($myDirectory);
if ($handle) {
    while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
        echo $file, '<br>';
    }
}
```

Take also a look at the examples on the corresponding manual pages of these functions.